# X-Axis labeled in a scatter plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I would like to do a scatter plot with two populations A and B. I am currently using zeros and ones to generate the scatter plot. So A is line up at x=0 and B and x=1. Is it possible to delete numbers from the x-axis and just add a string? So that it looks like a histogram?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. if you get a handle to the axes you can use the [`XTick` and `XTickLabel` properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) e.g.

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'XTickLabel', []);
```

to remove them entirely, or

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [0 1], 'XTickLabel', {'this one', 'that one'});
```

Or just play with properties until you find something you like ;)

(you can also fiddle with things via the [figure property editor](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-tools--interactive-plotting.html#f9-43442) in the GUI if you don't want to do it programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
scatter(x,y);
labels = {'A', 'B'}
set(gca,'XTick',0:1)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labels)
```

`set(gca,'XTick',0:1)` is used to only place ticks on 0 and 1. Similarly, for all integers within range: `0:max(x)`.

`set(gca,'XTickLabel',labels)` is used to change the name of the ticks. Note that the length of `labels` must be equal to the number of ticks.